# AutoIt - Class of Windows Error Pop-ups

Tags: windows, popup, autoit

I would like to be able to automate the detection of Windows pop-ups through using an AutoIt script, which would run in background. Basically, I have an AutoIt script doing some stuff on my OS, and I need to know if everything worked fine or not. Currently, Windows does pop an error when certains conditions are met. The only thing I want is a log file saying "Everything worked/crashed", no handling of the error is needed. I am talking about those redish Windows pop-ups making a terrible sound. Only those should be captured by my script.

I thought about using the `WinWaitActive` function with the right class, which would return `Success` if a pop-up actually... pops. The problem is that I need this *right class*, and I did not find anything about it. If someone has any idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AutoIt Window Information Tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to find this out. There's a link to "Window Titles" on this page and from there you can get to "advanced modes", go and read it and you should be ready to solve your problem! Else ask again after trying you're luck =)